# Angular 4: How to show Re-login Dialog/Modal from intercepter

Tags: javascript, angular

**Problem statment**

I am very new to Angular 4 and struggling to find out how to get a user re-logging when the token expires.

**Lets dig into code**

I have an `response intercepter` that checks the response code for `401` error

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do(
      // success responses
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // I do not want to do anything here... just pass
        }
      },
      // error responses
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            //here is where I need to show a modal
            //OH! STACKOVER-FLOW PLEASE BLESS ME
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

**Just Informing**
The application is too modular as every `component` is a module itself. Like for an example : `Login Component` is a module itself and `Registration` is Another module which are included in a the root module using routes...

So could you please help me with the best practice to solve this riddle?

Comment: You could broadcast/emit a message to your base component to show a login modal box through a template -- but that's one way.

Comment: so why it's a problem to show dialog? or your "intercept" subscribtion is inside of a service?

Comment: @sajal's comment is a way to go about things if you need a modal for loggin in to the app after expiration of token

Comment: `Sajal` your suggestion is good. `2oppin` I was wondering if I can use observable in this scenario (I donot know how, might be creating a seperate service that handles showing relogin component)) `rahulSingh` I am still looking for suggestions so that we may evaluate the best practice. Either I will get some answers or I write it myself after confirming what is good if not best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Angular4 CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to check whether user logged in or not, I think it would works the same way as your approach.
Anyway in your canActivate service or inside of your hook I can see 2 solutions:

1) as @Sajal mentioned - broadcast event:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {

    heyStopRightThere: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
      Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    ...
              if (err.status === 401) {
                   this.heyStopRightThere.emit();
              }
    ...
      }
}
```

and then in all secured components

```
constructor(
        private _yrSvc: YourService
        ) {
    }

    showLoginDialog() {
        //enable component LoginDialog that embeded in
        // <loginDialog *ngIf="notLoggedIn"></loginDialog>
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this._yrSvc.heyStopRightThere.subscribe(() =>
             showLoginDialog()
        );
    }
```

2) Redirect with param to callback:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {
     constructor(private router: Router){}
     intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
       Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       ...
           if (err.status === 401) {
               this.router.navigate(['/login', {callback: location.href}]);
           }
       ...
     }
```

And then your Login component you can draw your dialog and redirect back to "callback" on success.